# innerHTML replaces whole document

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

I have a setInterval function which replaces text within a particular div element every second. I also have text in the body which I want to keep.

What is the easiest way to preserve the text in a document without .innerHTML overriding the whole document?

```
<html>
<div id="timer" </div>
<script>
         window.onload = setInterval(function(){refreshTime()},1000);
         function refreshTime()
         {
              document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = ""+DAYS+" Days:"+HOURS+" Hours:"+(minutes)+" Minutes:"+seconds+" ;
               time = time+1;}
</script>
<body>
    <p>
      sOME TEXT I WANT TO KEEP ON 
    </p>

</body>
```

I've removed a lot of unncessary code to make it easier for you guys to read. I hope you guys understand what I'm asking. This is my first time on SO

Comment: Why do you have a `<div` element (with a missing closing `>`) declared before the `<body>` tag? Also, not what you were asking about, but it doesn't make sense to assign the return value from `setInterval()` (which will be a number that is an id you can later use with `clearInterval()`) as an `.onload` handler.

Comment: I was just experimenting. 
didn't know that setInterval returns an id that you can use with clearInterval. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="timer" </div>
```

change it to `<div id="timer"></div>`
And paste it in `body` tag

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. 
I take it that because "timer" is a child of body now, it doesn't replace the whole text?